# Python os.system() in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using Python to call someone's program:

```
print cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

This following is the output of the `print` command, which shows `cmd` calls `sclite` with a few parameters and then redirects the output to `dump`.

```
C:/travel/sctk-2.4.0/bin/sclite -r C:/travel/tempRef.txt -h C:/travel/tempTrans.txt -i spu_id > C:/travel/dump
```

When I run the command in cygwin, `dump` contains the desired output.  When I open Python in cygwin and use `os.system(cmd)` there, `dump` contains the desired output.  If I run my Python script from cygwin, `dump` contains the desired output.  When I run my Python script in Eclipse, `dump` contains nothing, i.e., the file is created but nothing is written to it.

I've tried the same with `subprocess(cmd,shell=True)` with the same results: running the script in Eclipse results in an empty file while the others work fine.  I'm guessing there's something wrong with Eclipse/Pydev, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Time to stop using Eclipse...

Comment: If you end up happening to go that^ route, maybe try Visual Studio + http://pytools.codeplex.com/...

Comment: I don't work on Windows -- and haven't for a long time, but does the shell redirection ( > ) work in a standard Windows shell?  Could that be the problem?

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, it works in a Windows shell... I believe it has done so for a long time too.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to this problem could be using Popen --

```
from subprocess import Popen
cmd="C:/travel/sctk-2.4.0/bin/sclite -r C:/travel/tempRef.txt -h C:/travel/tempTrans.txt -i spu_id"
f=open('C:/travel/dump','w')
p=Popen(cmd.split(),stdout=f)
```

But that still doesn't explain your strange behavior in Eclipse...